# Electron - Javascript (ES6) - import remote Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron

**EDIT :

02/09 -** It seems that the import code is fine (like the one in the response), but my class code is not good (bad ES6 ? bad transpilation ?)

**Initial post :**
I'm trying to import a remote class from my electron app.

- I have a static server to host my html/js files
- I'd like to import a class from that server, in order to use it in the main process of my electron app.

Is it possible ?

I found some solution like :

```
var vm = require('vm')
var concat = require('concat-stream');
require('http')
  .get(
    {
      host: 'localhost', 
      port: 8123, 
      path:"/dist/SomeViewModel.js" 
    }, 
    function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.pipe(concat({ encoding: 'string' }, function(remoteSrc) {
        vm.runInThisContext(remoteSrc, 'remote_modules/SomeViewModel.js')
      }));
    } );
```

it seems to tun without error, but I don't understand how to use it ...
`var someVM = new SomeViewModel()` doesn't work for example (not surprised ...).

Here is SomeViewModel :

```
export default class SomeViewModel {
  constructor(options) {
    this.element1 = options.element1,
    this.element2 = options.element2
  };
}
```

The class is babelized and becomes that :

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var SomeViewModel = function SomeViewModel(options) {
  _classCallCheck(this, SomeViewModel);

  this.element1 = options.element1, this.element2 = options.element2;
};

exports["default"] = SomeViewModel;
module.exports = exports["default"];

},{}]},{},[1]);

//# sourceMappingURL=SomeViewModel.js.map
```

Is that a good way to go ? (I know about security, it's just how to)

Comment: What's the need for `vm.runInThisContext`? If your external JS file is just a class, what's wrong with `var SomeViewModel = require('./remote_modules/SomeViewModel.js')`?

Comment: hi, I get a `Cannot find module './remote_modules/SomeViewModel.js'` Error. I don't understand at what that `./remote_modules` correspond as the path is not created.

(The code come from another StackOverflow post) and I didn't find any other information on that one

Comment: W̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶r̶s̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶n̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶.̶ ̶P̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶c̶t̶u̶a̶l̶ ̶l̶o̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶.̶ edit: I have reread your question and now understand this file is coming from some external server. The first block of JS code in your question, is it in the main process or the renderer process?

Comment: That code is in the main process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would download the file and store it on disk, and once it is finished, require the file.

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/SomeViewModel.js');
http.get({
    // your options
}, function (res) {
    // set encoding, etc.
    res.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
        file.close(function() {
            // do stuff
            // var SomeViewModel = require('./tmp/SomeViewModel.js');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The file is downloaded, the require run. But when I try to instantiate SomeViewModel I get an error saying `TypeError: SomeViewModel is not a function`. I already had that error before and I think it's my class that is not good. Maybe it come from my babel/gulp/... config. I think the starting code was good (your last code show that the problem is not from here). I close that issue and open a new one. Thank you very much !  
PS: The file need to be created before running that code or it through an exception.

Comment: 1) You could test the above code but use different, very simple program in place of the ES6 class in SomeViewModel.js. 2) As for the need to create the file before, I believe you only need the tmp folder created, node will create the file if it has to. 3) If this code answered your question, please accept is as the answer. Thanks

Comment: 1) `TypeError: xxx is not a function`, in this case seems to correspond to the `this` in the `ES6 constructor` that have a problem when `babelized`.
- 2) The folder && the file needed to be here :-s